# no newlines for python interactive console over socket

Tags: python, sockets

In a C program embedding the python interpreter, I spawn a python interactive console over a TCP socket.

```
import socket
import code
import sys

s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 2000))
s.listen(1)
c = s.accept()[0] # client socket

def sread(s, len):
        return s.recv(len)
def swrite(s, str):
        return s.sendall(str)
def sreadline(s):
        return sread(s, 256) # lazy implementation for quick testing
socket.socket.read = sread
socket.socket.write = swrite
socket.socket.readline = sreadline
sys.stdin = c
sys.stdout = c
sys.stderr = c
code.interact() # runs the interactive console
```

This basically works.
But, the interactive console never ever issues any end-of-line character when returning the result of some user input statement.
In other words we get things like this:

```
nc localhost 2000
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:53:55) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> 1+1
2>>>
```

We see no CR-LF after the result '2' send by the interpreter in response to the user input '1+1', and before the next prompt '>>>'.
The absence of any end-of-line character (CR and/or LF) is confirmed by examining the output of the user end of the socket in hexadecimal, or examining the string that is about to be written to the socket in function swrite().

Now why are no end-of-line characters issued by the interactive console?

Can it be fixed and how?

Comment: If you could include enough code to reproduce the problem, it'd make it easier to answer.

Comment: Sure, done. Btw I found a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to do with the [`softspace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.softspace) file attribute which determines when Python should send newlines, and needs to be writable in order for Python to function correctly.

Because you're setting `sys.stdout` to a 'read-only' socket object, the attribute can't be set, so you'll get problems with text output.

You could fix it by defining a `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` method in the same way as you do the other methods, but it's a complete hack, so you'd be better off with your 'wrapper' solution.

Comment: Trying to check this, I observed that my wrapper object comes out with a new 'softspace' attribute after being used, which confirms your first assertion (I also tried to add this attribute myself to socket before but did not find how). For the second assertion, I added __getattr__/__setattr__ to the socket class and observe that __getattr__ is called for both 'softspace' and 'encoding' while __setattr__ is never called, and I fail to solve my initial problem using __getattr__/__setattr__, so is there something special about implementing __getattr__/__setattr__ for socket?

Comment: ok... using getattr/setattr actually works when implemented correctly

Answer (score 1):

The question about the 'why' is still open, but as to how to fix it, here is solution.
Instead of adding read/write/readline methods to the socket.socket class, make a wrapper of the socket.socket class:

```
import socket
import code
import sys

s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 2000))
s.listen(1)
c = s.accept()[0] # client socket

class sw: # socket wrapper
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s
    def read(self, len):
            return self.s.recv(len)
    def write(self, str):
            return self.s.send(str)
    def readline(self):
            return self.read(256) # lazy implementation for quick testing
c = sw(c)
sys.stdin = c
sys.stdout = c
sys.stderr = c
code.interact() # runs the interactive console
```

Now this works as expected, but for an unknown reason.

```
nc localhost 2000
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> 1+1
2
>>>
```