# How can I enter Python's pdb on an uncaught exception when I have no console

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, postmortem-debugging

I'm running a Python application in our development shop. It's called from another GUI application. When it fails, I would like to have a console appear where it's stopped in pdb post-mortem debugging so I can walk over and see what's going on when our users had a problem.

I've tried setting excepthook at the top of my program:

```
def pcs_debugger(type, value, tb):
    traceback.print_exception(type, value, tb)
    pdb.pm()

sys.excepthook = pcs_debugger
```

And that works great except for when I don't already have a console, like when I launch it with pythonw or when it's being called from this other GUI application not written in Python.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks

UPDATE: I forgot to mention this is all on Windows 7

UPDATE: Adding minimal code example. Note that this works the way I want it to if I launch it with python.exe, but not pythonw.exe, and pythonw is more similar to what I have going on in my environment, where I actually have a C# GUI loading up this Python code from within a dll.

```
import pdb, sys, traceback, wx

def my_debugger(type, value, tb):
    traceback.print_exception(type, value, tb)
    pdb.pm()

sys.excepthook = my_debugger

class MyApp(wx.App):

    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame("Hello World", (50, 60), (450, 340))
        frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, title, pos, size):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, title, pos, size)
        menuFile = wx.Menu()
        menuFile.Append(1, "&About...")
        menuFile.AppendSeparator()
        menuFile.Append(2, "E&xit")
        menuFile.Append(3, "&Fail")
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(menuFile, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.SetStatusText("Welcome to wxPython!")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, id=1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, id=2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnFail, id=3)

    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.Close()

    def OnAbout(self, event):
        wx.MessageBox("This is a wxPython Hello World Sample",
                      "About Hello World", wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION, self)

    def OnFail(self, event):
        a = 1
        b = 0
        self.SetStatusText('about to divide by 0')
        c = a / b
        print 'here it is {}'.format(c)
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: (Assuming your running on \*nix) I'm not sure you *can* get a terminal from another running process.  One alternative may be to have your logger capture the exception information and forward to a logging server.  That won't give you interactive debugging, though.

Comment: Can you provide a SSCCE (minimal example code)? I'm not very familiar with Python yet and would like to reproduce the problem to provide an answer.

Comment: There is the [AeDebug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb204634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) registry key where you can configure a debugger for an application. Never used it with PDB, but maybe you can make it work

Answer (score 0):

You could accept a connection over a tcp connection on localhost. This question has an example of doing this. [no newlines for python interactive console over socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155480/no-newlines-for-python-interactive-console-over-socket)